# Changing mass with velocity

Tags: classical-mechanics, momentum, mass, velocity

I was wondering that a change in velocity can change the mass of an object slightly. I thought of this since p=mv so if we rearrange it to be m=p/v. Does this mean that a change in momentum or velocity can actually change the mass?

Comment: [See here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91974/increase-in-mass-with-velocity).

Comment: What do you have in mind that can change momentum but not change velocity (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this equation, $p = mv$. If you increase the velocity and keep $p$ constant, yes you must have had an increase in mass. The question is, what does it mean for $p$ to be constant? It is *defined* by the product of mass and velocity. So you have done nothing to make predictions, you have just stated what you would call mass if you increased v and kept p the same. OR since mass and velocity are more readily known as measured quantities to the layman, you have said increasing v and lowering m keeps mv the same. See? you've said nothing of any value

Answer (score 0):

Note, for a small change in $p$ (and $v$, as their correlation is 1, or $m$ depending on normalization):

$$ \delta m = \frac d {dp}({\frac p v})\delta p+ \frac d {dv}({\frac p v})\delta v $$

$$ \delta m = \frac{\delta p} v - \frac{p\delta v}{v^2}$$

Since:

$$ \delta p = m \delta v$$

we get:

$$ \delta m = \frac{\delta p} v - \frac{p\delta p/m}{v^2}$$

$$ \delta m = \delta p(\frac 1 v - \frac{v}{v^2})$$

$$ \delta m = \delta p(\frac 1 v - \frac{1}{v}) = 0$$

So, no.